# Can't pass table variable to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following:

```
IF TYPE_ID(N'LabelFunctions') IS NULL
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Creating LabelFunctions'
    CREATE TYPE [dbo].[LabelFunctions]
    AS TABLE (Label NVARCHAR(25));
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    Print 'already created!'
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE #linkKeyFobCommand  
(  
    @labels AS [dbo].[LabelFunctions] ReadOnly,
    @switchConfig NVARCHAR(25)
)  
AS  
BEGIN  
    PRINT 'foo';
END;  
GO
```

I get the following output:

> already created
>
> Msg 2715, Level 16, State 3, Procedure #linkKeyFobCommand, Line 2
>   Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type dbo.LabelFunctions. Parameter or variable '@labels' has an invalid data type.

Why can the procedure not find my `LabelFunctions` data type?

Comment: Why is your procedure `#linkKeyFobCommand` and not `dbo.linkKeyFobCommand`? If you insist on creating a temporary procedure in tempdb, you need to create the type there too (as well as, possibly, your user database(s)). And you will need to create it again after every SQL Server service restart. Why not just create a user procedure that can use the type defined in your user database? What are you gaining from a #temporary procedure?

Comment: @marc_s 2012 Enterprise edition.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I see. It is a temporary procedure as it is only going to be used in a single deployment. Given your input, I'll simply create and then drop the stored procedure. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you even need a procedure? You know you can insert into a variable declared as `dbo.LabelFunctions`, right? Again, what are you getting out of a procedure?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have a collection of switchConfigs, each with a collection of labels. To persist those entities, the original script had pretty much the same block of code written a dozen times. By creating a procedure, I am centralizing the logic into one spot.